# Firebase simple query date range ... doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an array with some keys :

```
['-KSH1rJ8BgbOWKdwdn0J', '-KSH0B8MfPCB2_zI8H3Q', ...];
```

And for each key, I would like to know if "ts_exp" which is the expiration timestamp is between yesterday and tomorrow which are both timestamps.

```
 var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'day').format("x");
 var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').format("x");

 foreach(... as key){
        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('demandes').child(key)
        .orderByChild('ts_exp')
        .startAt(yesterday)
        .endAt(tomorrow);

        rootRef.once("value", function(messageSnapshot) {
          console.log(messageSnapshot.val()); // always return null
        });
    }
```

**What's wrong with this query? This is this always null  (But I have a "demande" which have an "ts_exp" between this 2 values). I did .indexOn "ts_exp" in my firebase rules also.**
Thank you

This is the data structure :

```
 -demandes
    ----- -KSH1rJ8BgbOWKdwdn0J
    ---------- ts_exp : 14123123123,
    ---------- title : "pipo1",
    ---------- desc : "desc"
    ----- -KSH0B8MfPCB2_zI8H3Q
    ---------- ts_exp : 14123176576,
    ---------- title : "pipo2",
    ---------- desc : "desc2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ts_exp values are numbers (14123123123) but your startAt / endAt are strings, and Firebase Database sorts all numbers before all strings, so your query is searching a range with no data.

Untested, but try:

```
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'day').valueOf();
var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').valueOf();
```

Comment: Thank you but where I remove `.child(key)` and do the query with my yesterday and tomorrow values in all the `demandes` path, the data are correctly showed and filtered. All I want to know (without loading all the `demandes` datas) is if one demand with specific key is between this range.

Comment: You can't sensibly compare strings and numbers. Convert the output from moment.js to a number, e.g. with `.startAt(parseInt(yesterday))`. See http://jsbin.com/noziri/edit?js,console

Comment: Whoa thank you M. Puffelen. I tried `firebase.database().ref('demandes').child(key).orderByChild('ts_exp')
          .startAt(parseInt(yesterday))
          .endAt(parseInt(tomorrow));` but still the same results ...

Comment: Ok so when I removed `.child(key)` it worked. So I think I have to loop through all the `demandes` path (1500 items), collect results (450 in all country) and for each do a simple filter to see if the key is in array (5 array keys = 5 near Geofire key) ... Si I think it's a lot of bandwidth waste ? What do you think ? Is there another way to do what I want ? Thank you